# Undefined: When I fetch data from graphql in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, graphql, next.js

I am new to fetching data from graphql in Next.js. When I it gives me `undefined`. It works fine on the playground but got a problem on next.js.

Here is the graphql API

`https://shoplly-api.techawks.io/graphql`

Here is the code Hero.js for displaying the categories data.

```
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, gql } from "@apollo/client";
const Hero = ({ categories }) => {
  console.log(categories);
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="flex space-x-4 justify-center items-center">
        <div>Products</div>
        <div>Contact us</div>
        <div>About us</div>
        <div>Contact us</div>
        <div>About us</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Hero;

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const client = new ApolloClient({
    uri: "https://shoplly-api.techawks.io/graphql",
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  });
  const { data } = await client.query({
    query: gql`
      query {
        categories {
          name
        }
      }
    `,
  });
  console.log(categories);
  return {
    props: {
      categories: data.categories,
    },
  };
}
```

When I console log `categories` object it returns undefined? What I actually missed in this case?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Radosvet mentioned, `categories` isn't defined in `getStaticProps`, so that will be undefined there.

In Next.js, `getStaticProps` is only called from page components. So, if you are using `<Hero />` as a regular React component in another page, `getStaticProps` won't be called, and no props will be passed to `Hero`. Try either using Hero.js as a page, meaning it should be in the `pages` directory of your project and go to `localhost:3000/hero`, or define `getStaticProps` in whatever page is using that component, and pass the props from the page into `Hero`. Something like this:

```js
import Hero from "../components/hero";
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, gql } from "@apollo/client";

export default function Home({ categories }) {
  return <Hero categories={categories} />;
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const client = new ApolloClient({
    uri: "https://shoplly-api.techawks.io/graphql",
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  });
  const { data } = await client.query({
    query: gql`
      query {
        categories {
          name
        }
      }
    `,
  });
  return {
    props: {
      categories: data.categories,
    },
  };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In `getStaticProps` you are never defining just the `categories`. Try using `data.categories`

Comment: Can you please show me where to put `data.categories` . Sorry I am barely new to this code? Thanks for your response

Comment: You've got two logs, the one in ```getStaticProps```, try to ```console.log(data.categories)``` instead of just  ```console.log(categories)```

Comment: Your suggestion doesn't work for me. I wanted to consume the data in the Hero component section. Thanks for your answer. Appreciate it.